# Is it possible to extend a library class extend MY_Controller class

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to extend a library class extend MY_Controller class in application -  core folder.

Comment: Start with [docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can even totally replace them, but are rarely needed. 
See this manual: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html
(For Legacy CodeIgniter)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are several approaches. This question has been asked and answered many times on Stack Overflow. Search this site for **extending CI_Controller**

This [page discusses](http://avenir.ro/codeigniter-tutorials/no-more-my_controller-how-you-can-create-more-than-one-base-controller/) some of the options.

Comment: extending class is a library class and need to extend class in the application  -> core of codeigniter

Comment: But the same issues/solutions apply.